# Generate new hash for each user email using PHP and Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, hash

I am using [Bootstrap Data Table](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/) to generate a user table and I want to display each users avatar in the table which I have working now. I allow users to use gravatar, but I am also forcing the default to be the retro icon. The problem that I have is that it generates the same hash for each user causing their icons to be the same.

Here is my JS code:

```
function usernameFormatter(value, row) {
        var id = row.id;
        var email = row.email;
        var avatarType = row.avatar_type;
        var avatar = '../users/' + row.avatar;

        if(avatarType == 'Gravatar'){
            var retro = 'retro';
            var urlencode = <?php echo urlencode( retro ); ?>;
            var hash = '<?php echo md5( strtolower( trim( email ) ) ); ?>';
            var avatar = 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/' + hash + '?d=' + urlencode;              
        }
        return '<a href="../users/profile.php?userid=' + id + '" target="_blank"><img src="' + avatar + '" style="width: 32px;margin-right: 5px;">' + value + '</a>';
    }
```

I am having trouble writing, for each email address use a different hash. Can someone guide me in the right direction? Any code examples you have is much appreciated.

Comment: Your PHP code shown is invalid.

Comment: how? can you explain? everything works fine. the only problem i have is the same hash is being generated.

Comment: Code looks correct except for the javascript should be if(avatarType === 'gravatar')

Comment: @iamthestreets The code `<?php echo md5( strtolower( trim( email ) ) ); ?>` is invalid. PHP variables start with a `$` and you can't access JavaScript variables in the fashion shown.

Answer (score 1):

```
        var email = email;
        var urlencode = <?php echo urlencode( retro ); ?>;
        var hash = '<?php echo md5( strtolower( trim( email ) ) ); ?>';
```

The problem is you can't use a JS variable in PHP without passing it to the server first. When PHP is processing, it has no idea what `email` is.

Comment: I am getting the email from the table by setting an email var like this `var email = row.email;` I will update my code above to include only one var. Technically i don't need `var email = email;` because i set it above using `var email = row.email;`

Comment: @iamthestreets PHP has no access to JS variables.

Answer (score 0):

> how? can you explain? everything works fine. the only problem i have is the same hash is being generated.

```
<?php echo md5( strtolower( trim( email ) ) ); ?>
```

That's because you're working on the **string** 'email', not the **value** email. PHP variables are named with `$`, and you won't be able to access JavaScript variables in the manner you showed without using AJAX to communicate between the browser and the server.

If you run your code with warnings on, you'll get this message:

> Notice: Use of undefined constant email - assumed 'email' in - on line ...

This is why the hash is the same at all times - your code is actually doing:

```
<?php echo md5( strtolower( trim( 'email' ) ) ); ?>
```

Comment: @iamthestreets It needs a complete rewrite after you do some research into AJAX.

Comment: Actually the url is correct just with the same hash. Why does the other variable work? For example I set a var like this `var retro = 'retro';` and then set this `var urlencode = <?php echo urlencode( retro ); ?>` and this outputs retro. If i change the retro var to retros like this `var retro = 'retros';` it changes it in the php echo to retros when viewing the url

Comment: @iamthestreets Have you tested that? `var retro='retro'; var urlencode = <?php echo urlencode( retro ); ?>` and `var retro='test'; var urlencode = <?php echo urlencode( retro ); ?>` will have the same hash.

Comment: retro is a paramenter in the url so if i set this `var retro = 'retro';` it will add a parameter to the end of the url like this `http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0c83f57c786a0b4a39efab23731c7ebc?d=retro` if I change it to this this `var retro = 'retros';` the url will show like this `http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0c83f57c786a0b4a39efab23731c7ebc?d=retros` i have tested this

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just using a JS equivalent MD5 like this:

```
var MD5=function(s){function L(k,d){return(k<<d)|(k>>>(32-d))}function K(G,k){var I,d,F,H,x;F=(G&2147483648);H=(k&2147483648);I=(G&1073741824);d=(k&1073741824);x=(G&1073741823)+(k&1073741823);if(I&d){return(x^2147483648^F^H)}if(I|d){if(x&1073741824){return(x^3221225472^F^H)}else{return(x^1073741824^F^H)}}else{return(x^F^H)}}function r(d,F,k){return(d&F)|((~d)&k)}function q(d,F,k){return(d&k)|(F&(~k))}function p(d,F,k){return(d^F^k)}function n(d,F,k){return(F^(d|(~k)))}function u(G,F,aa,Z,k,H,I){G=K(G,K(K(r(F,aa,Z),k),I));return K(L(G,H),F)}function f(G,F,aa,Z,k,H,I){G=K(G,K(K(q(F,aa,Z),k),I));return K(L(G,H),F)}function D(G,F,aa,Z,k,H,I){G=K(G,K(K(p(F,aa,Z),k),I));return K(L(G,H),F)}function t(G,F,aa,Z,k,H,I){G=K(G,K(K(n(F,aa,Z),k),I));return K(L(G,H),F)}function e(G){var Z;var F=G.length;var x=F+8;var k=(x-(x%64))/64;var I=(k+1)*16;var aa=Array(I-1);var d=0;var H=0;while(H<F){Z=(H-(H%4))/4;d=(H%4)*8;aa[Z]=(aa[Z]|(G.charCodeAt(H)<<d));H++}Z=(H-(H%4))/4;d=(H%4)*8;aa[Z]=aa[Z]|(128<<d);aa[I-2]=F<<3;aa[I-1]=F>>>29;return aa}function B(x){var k="",F="",G,d;for(d=0;d<=3;d++){G=(x>>>(d*8))&255;F="0"+G.toString(16);k=k+F.substr(F.length-2,2)}return k}function J(k){k=k.replace(/rn/g,"n");var d="";for(var F=0;F<k.length;F++){var x=k.charCodeAt(F);if(x<128){d+=String.fromCharCode(x)}else{if((x>127)&&(x<2048)){d+=String.fromCharCode((x>>6)|192);d+=String.fromCharCode((x&63)|128)}else{d+=String.fromCharCode((x>>12)|224);d+=String.fromCharCode(((x>>6)&63)|128);d+=String.fromCharCode((x&63)|128)}}}return d}var C=Array();var P,h,E,v,g,Y,X,W,V;var S=7,Q=12,N=17,M=22;var A=5,z=9,y=14,w=20;var o=4,m=11,l=16,j=23;var U=6,T=10,R=15,O=21;s=J(s);C=e(s);Y=1732584193;X=4023233417;W=2562383102;V=271733878;for(P=0;P<C.length;P+=16){h=Y;E=X;v=W;g=V;Y=u(Y,X,W,V,C[P+0],S,3614090360);V=u(V,Y,X,W,C[P+1],Q,3905402710);W=u(W,V,Y,X,C[P+2],N,606105819);X=u(X,W,V,Y,C[P+3],M,3250441966);Y=u(Y,X,W,V,C[P+4],S,4118548399);V=u(V,Y,X,W,C[P+5],Q,1200080426);W=u(W,V,Y,X,C[P+6],N,2821735955);X=u(X,W,V,Y,C[P+7],M,4249261313);Y=u(Y,X,W,V,C[P+8],S,1770035416);V=u(V,Y,X,W,C[P+9],Q,2336552879);W=u(W,V,Y,X,C[P+10],N,4294925233);X=u(X,W,V,Y,C[P+11],M,2304563134);Y=u(Y,X,W,V,C[P+12],S,1804603682);V=u(V,Y,X,W,C[P+13],Q,4254626195);W=u(W,V,Y,X,C[P+14],N,2792965006);X=u(X,W,V,Y,C[P+15],M,1236535329);Y=f(Y,X,W,V,C[P+1],A,4129170786);V=f(V,Y,X,W,C[P+6],z,3225465664);W=f(W,V,Y,X,C[P+11],y,643717713);X=f(X,W,V,Y,C[P+0],w,3921069994);Y=f(Y,X,W,V,C[P+5],A,3593408605);V=f(V,Y,X,W,C[P+10],z,38016083);W=f(W,V,Y,X,C[P+15],y,3634488961);X=f(X,W,V,Y,C[P+4],w,3889429448);Y=f(Y,X,W,V,C[P+9],A,568446438);V=f(V,Y,X,W,C[P+14],z,3275163606);W=f(W,V,Y,X,C[P+3],y,4107603335);X=f(X,W,V,Y,C[P+8],w,1163531501);Y=f(Y,X,W,V,C[P+13],A,2850285829);V=f(V,Y,X,W,C[P+2],z,4243563512);W=f(W,V,Y,X,C[P+7],y,1735328473);X=f(X,W,V,Y,C[P+12],w,2368359562);Y=D(Y,X,W,V,C[P+5],o,4294588738);V=D(V,Y,X,W,C[P+8],m,2272392833);W=D(W,V,Y,X,C[P+11],l,1839030562);X=D(X,W,V,Y,C[P+14],j,4259657740);Y=D(Y,X,W,V,C[P+1],o,2763975236);V=D(V,Y,X,W,C[P+4],m,1272893353);W=D(W,V,Y,X,C[P+7],l,4139469664);X=D(X,W,V,Y,C[P+10],j,3200236656);Y=D(Y,X,W,V,C[P+13],o,681279174);V=D(V,Y,X,W,C[P+0],m,3936430074);W=D(W,V,Y,X,C[P+3],l,3572445317);X=D(X,W,V,Y,C[P+6],j,76029189);Y=D(Y,X,W,V,C[P+9],o,3654602809);V=D(V,Y,X,W,C[P+12],m,3873151461);W=D(W,V,Y,X,C[P+15],l,530742520);X=D(X,W,V,Y,C[P+2],j,3299628645);Y=t(Y,X,W,V,C[P+0],U,4096336452);V=t(V,Y,X,W,C[P+7],T,1126891415);W=t(W,V,Y,X,C[P+14],R,2878612391);X=t(X,W,V,Y,C[P+5],O,4237533241);Y=t(Y,X,W,V,C[P+12],U,1700485571);V=t(V,Y,X,W,C[P+3],T,2399980690);W=t(W,V,Y,X,C[P+10],R,4293915773);X=t(X,W,V,Y,C[P+1],O,2240044497);Y=t(Y,X,W,V,C[P+8],U,1873313359);V=t(V,Y,X,W,C[P+15],T,4264355552);W=t(W,V,Y,X,C[P+6],R,2734768916);X=t(X,W,V,Y,C[P+13],O,1309151649);Y=t(Y,X,W,V,C[P+4],U,4149444226);V=t(V,Y,X,W,C[P+11],T,3174756917);W=t(W,V,Y,X,C[P+2],R,718787259);X=t(X,W,V,Y,C[P+9],O,3951481745);Y=K(Y,h);X=K(X,E);W=K(W,v);V=K(V,g)}var i=B(Y)+B(X)+B(W)+B(V);return i.toLowerCase()};
```

and then I set the hash var to this `var hash = MD5(email.trim().toLowerCase());`

This seems to have worked.